# Action_send intent not working for Email-ID field

Tags: android-intent, onclick, onclicklistener

I am trying to use `Action_send` intent for copying mail id and share the mail id with all installed sharable apps. But by default it is invoking the gmail app. The createChoose is not working properly.

```
 if (!textViewEmail.getText().toString().equals("") &&       !textViewEmail.getText().toString().equals("NA")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                textViewEmail.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

                try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Using"));

                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "There is no  client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }return true;
```

Comment: Do you want to share the Email Id in the textview to all the sharing medias installed in the App.?

Comment: Yes,Exactly..But not able to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailTextview.getText().toString());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Email Address to"));
```

Hope it helps you..!!